# How can I safely replace the contents of an ObservableCollection that's serving as a TreeView's ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3

I'm writing WinUI 3 desktop application. The main window consists of a `TreeView` with the names of car makes as the parent items, and car models as the children. Here's the relevant code:

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="Cars.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="using:Cars.Model"
    xmlns:view="using:Cars.View"
    xmlns:utility="using:Cars.View.Utility">
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
                        
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CarMakeTemplate" x:DataType="model:CarMake">
                <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=CarModels, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <view:CarMakeView CarMake="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteCarMake"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
            
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CarModelTemplate" x:DataType="model:CarModel">
                <TreeViewItem>
                    <view:CarModelView CarModel="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
            
            <utility:CarItemSelector
                x:Key="CarItemSelector"
                CarMakeTemplate="{StaticResource CarMakeTemplate}"
                CarModelTemplate="{StaticResource CarModelTemplate}" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Cars, Mode=OneWay}"  
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CarItemSelector}"
                  SelectionChanged="HandleSelectedCarMakeChanged">
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
    
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.cs`:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CarMake> Cars { get; set; } =
            new ()
            {
                new CarMake { Name = "Chevrolet", CarModels = { new CarModel { Name = "Camaro" }, new CarModel { Name = "Blazer" }, new CarModel { Name = "Beretta" } } },
                new CarMake { Name = "Land Rover", CarModels = { new CarModel { Name = "Discovery" }, new CarModel { Name = "LR3" }, new CarModel { Name = "Range Rover" } } },
                new CarMake { Name = "Quadra", CarModels = { new CarModel { Name = "Turbo-R 740" }, new CarModel { Name = "Type-66 Avenger" }} },
                new CarMake { Name = "Powell Motors", CarModels = { new CarModel { Name = "The Homer" }}}
            };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DeleteCarMake(object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventInfo)
        {
            var carMakeToDelete = ((Button) eventInfo.OriginalSource).DataContext as CarMake;
            var updatedCarMakes = new List<CarMake>(Cars);
            updatedCarMakes.Remove(carMakeToDelete!);
            
            Cars.Clear();
            foreach (CarMake carMake in updatedCarMakes)
            {
                Cars.Add(carMake);
            }
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cars));
        }

        private void HandleSelectedCarMakeChanged(TreeView sender, TreeViewSelectionChangedEventArgs info)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**The problem**: Here's the sequence of events that leads to the mystery exception:

1. The user clicks the "Delete" button.
2. `DeleteCarMake()` is invoked via callback.
3. `DeleteCarMake()` deletes the selected `CarMake` and completely resets the contents of the `Cars` `ObservableCollection`.
4. The next time the user clicks on the `TreeView` an exception is thrown.

The problem seems to be connected to the complete removal of the contents of `Cars` and subsequent copying of data back into `Cars` (note that `Cars` serves as the `ItemsSource` for the `TreeView`). If I simply remove the `carMakeToDelete` from `Cars`, the exception isn't thrown next time the user clicks the `TreeView`. However, for reasons which my simplified code can't express, I need to be able to completely `Clear()` `Cars`' contents at every delete, not just remove a single item.

The full call stack is [here](https://pastebin.com/wgkzK6mb) but as best I can tell the relevant part seems to be in the middle:

```
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!ViewModel::UpdateNodeSelection(struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::TreeViewNode const &,enum TreeViewNode::TreeNodeSelectionState const &)  Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!ViewModel::UpdateSelection(struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::TreeViewNode const &,enum TreeViewNode::TreeNodeSelectionState const &)  Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!SelectedTreeNodeVector::UpdateSelection(struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::TreeViewNode const &,enum TreeViewNode::TreeNodeSelectionState) Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!SelectedTreeNodeVector::RemoveAt(unsigned int)   Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!SelectedTreeNodeVector::Clear(void)  Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!winrt::impl::produce<class SelectedTreeNodeVector,struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::TreeViewNode> >::Clear(void)  Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IVector<struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject>,struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject>::Clear(void)   Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!ViewModel::SelectNode(struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::TreeViewNode const &,bool)    Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!TreeView::UpdateSelection(struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::TreeViewNode const &,bool)    Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!TreeViewItem::UpdateSelection(bool)  Unknown
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.dll!TreeViewItem::OnIsSelectedChanged(struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const &,struct winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty const &) Unknown
```

**What I'd like to know**: How can I safely `Clear()` the contents of my `Cars` `ObservableCollection` without causing an exception to be thrown the next time a user clicks on the `TreeView`?

**One possible clue**: If I don't define an event handler for the `TreeView`'s `SelectionChanged` event in my `MainWindow.xaml` then the exception never occurs. I'm not quite sure what this implies, but hopefully someone else can put together the pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: The WinUI team is actively answering WinUI questions in WinUI GitHub(https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues). You could try to submit your questions there.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll probably do that if I can’t get an answer on SO.

Comment: Why are you clearing and then repopulating the observable collection? Why don't you simply remove the one item that needs to be removed?

Comment: @slugster I considered whether I should add a note to explain that: this isn't my "real" code. It's a minimal reproducible example that I created purely for the purpose of highlighting my issue without any of the extraneous noise that comes with my actual codebase. Trust me when I say if you could see my original code it'd be clear why I have to clear the collection. It's non-negotiable: I can't simply remove one item, I have to clear out and repopulate the whole thing every time.

Comment: And yes I agree, in the code I've posted here clearing and repopulating the observable collection seems completely unmotivated. But again, in my original code there's a reason for it.

Comment: Fair enough. One option then is to assign a new ObervableCollection to the `Cars` property rather then resetting and repopulating the existing list, of course `Cars` would need to notify of property change. I have seen UIs (third party controls) struggle or crash in the past due to the way people have updated a bound ObservableCollection, sometimes it is more efficient to create a new one. Of course these comments do not necessarily solve your particular problem, hence why they're comments and not an answer :)

Comment: Turns out this is a [bug](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4075), apparently.

Comment: And I did try your suggestion, slugster, but apparently creating a new collection still triggers the bug the same as clearing the old one does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug slated to be fixed in the next preview release of WinUI 3. Source [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4075).